# NSSpeechSynthesizer voice/language relations

Tags: macos, cocoa

Unfortunately, I can speak only four languages, so how do I know which OS X voice I have to use if I know the language of a text? I can't find any information about it in Apple's documentation. Is there at least a table with voice/language?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the '+attributesForVoice:' method on NSSpeechSynthesizer. Included in the attributes is the locale, e.g.:

```
{
    VoiceAge = 35;
    VoiceDemoText = "\U0e2a\U0e27\U0e31\U0e2a\U0e14\U0e35\U0e04\U0e48\U0e30 \U0e14\U0e34\U0e09\U0e31\U0e19\U0e0a\U0e37\U0e48\U0e2dKanya";
    VoiceGender = VoiceGenderFemale;
    VoiceGroup = VoiceGroupCompact;
    VoiceIdentifier = "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.kanya";
    VoiceIndividuallySpokenCharacters = (
        {
            UnicodeCharBegin = 33;
            UnicodeCharEnd = 37;
        }, ...
    );
    VoiceLanguage = "th-TH";
    VoiceLocaleIdentifier = "th_TH";
    VoiceName = Kanya;
    VoiceNameRoot = Kanya;
    VoiceNumericID = 604143827;
    VoiceRelativeDesirability = 3800;
    VoiceShowInFullListOnly = 0;
    VoiceSupportedCharacters = (
        {
            UnicodeCharBegin = 33;
            UnicodeCharEnd = 37;
        }, ...
    );
    VoiceSynthesizerNumericID = 1886745202;
    VoiceVersion = "5.0.7";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it here for someone else.

```
let voices:[String:String] = [
  "en": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex",
  "ru": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.milena",
  "ar": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.tarik",
  "hu": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.mariska",
  "nl": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.ellen",
  "el": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.melina",
  "da": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.sara",
  "he": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.carmit",
  "id": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.damayanti",
  "es": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Jorge",
  "it": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.alice",
  "zh": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.ting-ting",
  "ko": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.yuna",
  "de": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.anna",
  "no": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.nora",
  "pl": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.zosia",
  "pt": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.joana",
  "ro": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.ioana",
  "sk": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.laura",
  "th": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.kanya",
  "tr": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.yelda",
  "fi": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.satu",
  "fr": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.thomas",
  "hi": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.lekha",
  "cs": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.zuzana",
  "sv": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.alva",
  "ja": "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.kyoko"
]
```